Find Assignation in Condition using a Regex
I need a regex with which I could find if there is any assignation inside conditions.
It needs to be as flexible as possible, because I will run this on many .php files to find such mistakes :
<?php
if($foo = "bar") { // instead of $foo == "bar"
    //...
}

I found a question similar to mine that helped me resolve this problem with this regex :
/if\s*\(.+[^!=<>]=[^=]/

However, it also matches where there is an '=' inside a string which is not what I wanted :
<?php
if($foo != '=') {
    //...
}

Note that it should also work on complex conditions with many comparisons such as :
if($foo == 0 && ($bar == 1 || $fooBar = 1) { // Instead of $fooBar == 1
    // ...
}

It is quite a challenging regex to find, and I would be very gratefull if I could get some help !

I don't think regex is sufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by PHP. For much of the same reason you shouldn't parse (X)HTML with regex, I believe the same applies to PHP. Sure you can use regex in smaller pieces as part of a parser that does things like clean, and tokenize, etc. In PHP, I'd reach for the tokenizer. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php

Thank you @Ultimater, I never thought that PHP would not be a regular language. I will find out how to use tokenizers, if it's a better alternative !

I think you will not find one regex that does what you want. I would suggest some kind of grep for if statments with each output line giving filename, line number and text-of-line. Then remove all == and '=' from the results. (Replacing them with __EQEQ__ and __CHAR_EQ__ etc may be better for distinguishing valid from potentially-invalid.) Next remove all found lines without a =. You may see other common valid patterns that you can exclude. The remaining lines should have the expressions you want to find, plus other valid expressions.

The initial goal is to browse PHP files in order to find assignations inside conditions.
My first approach was to use regular expressions. However, PHP is not a regular language, so we shouldn't use regex with it. (I don't believe a demonstration is needed, let me know if it is)
The solution I found involve a simple loop using tokenizers. I will share it in case someone find it usefull.
$path = 'path/to/file.php';
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$tokens = token_get_all($content);

$inCondition = false;
$parenthesis = 0;

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
        $token = $token[1];
    }

    switch ($token) {
        case 'if':
            $inCondition = true;
            break;
        case '(' :
            if ($inCondition) {
                $parenthesis++;
            }
            break;
        case '=':
            if ($inCondition && $parenthesis === 1) {
                throw new Exception("Assignment in if condition !");
            }
            break;
        case ')':
            if ($inCondition) {
                $parenthesis--;
                if ($parenthesis === 0) {
                    $inCondition = false;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

I believe this code sample could get some improvement, but it works very well !

You can try limiting the set of characters that identify the variable name, so as not to use . which also includes equality signs:
if\s*\([$\w-]+\s*[^!=<>]=[^=]

If there is always a variable in your conditions, and if you use multiple conditions such as if($foo == "bar" && $tmp = 'tmp'), you can reduce the regex like this:
[$\w-]+\s*[^!=<>]=[^=]


It is a good proposition, thanks ! But It doesn't work with complex conditions with many comparisons. I will add clarification to my question.
Could I ask why do you use a capturing group for the '=', and why do you specify that there is only one opening parenthesis \({1} ? Also, what is the utility of the {1,1}quantifier ?

Actually, I started from the regex of the answer to the question you linked. All three things you listed are superfluous and can be removed. Can you add some examples of complex conditions you are using?

You can use this
/if\s*\(\s*[^!=<>\n]*=[^=\n]*\)/


Example

FYI: I don't know what you're trying to archive. I have provided a solution based on your question. (Regex)


It does work well, but it doesn't work with conditions that makes more than one comparison. My bad, I should have been more precise.  Should I be exhaustive about why and how I will use this ? I thought it would be easier to go straight to the point.
